# Pegar valores de somente uma linha de uma tabela

Tags: php, mysql

Olá, tenho um projeto, e gostaria que, quando o usuário entrasse em sua conta, pudesse, através de uma ação PHP, ver seus dados básicos, pegando somente valores daquela tabela, eis o que tenho até o momento:

```
$selec = "SELECT * FROM usuarios";
$selec_query = mysql_query($selec) or die(mysql_error());

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($selec_query);
        $nome = $row['nomealuno'];
        $cidade = $row['cidadealuno'];
        $uf = $row['ufaluno'];
        $nome = $row['nomealuno'];
        $datanasc = $row['datanascaluno'];

        echo "Login: ";
        echo $row['login'];
        echo "<br> Nome: ";
        echo "$nome";
        echo "<br> Cidade: ";
        echo "$cidade";
        echo "<br> UF: ";
        echo "$uf";
        echo "<br> Data de nascimento: ";
        echo "$datanasc";
```

O problema é que aparece somente o primeiro login cadastrado, e todos os campos das tabelas estão com os respectivos nomes, não encontrei nenhum problema igual ao meu aqui, muito menos um problema evidente no codigo.

Comment: Não falta um `where` no seu select?

Comment: @jbueno Já tentei com `where`, poderia me dar um exemplo?

Comment: Sim. Antes me diz uma coisa, você tem o ID do usuário que está logado salvo em algum lugar, certo?

Comment: @jbueno não tenho, só tenho o cookie do login, não sei como pegar a id do usuario automaticamente, poderia me mostrar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essa *query*

```
$selec = "SELECT * FROM usuarios";
```

Está selecionando todos os registros da tabela `usuarios`.

Aqui

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($selec_query);
```

`$row` recebe uma linha do resultado (a primeira nesse caso).

O que você precisa fazer é limitar o seu `select` para trazer apenas o registro do usuário que desejas apresentar a informação. Para isso será necessário adicionar uma cláusula `where` na *query*.

```
$selec = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id = $idUsuario";
```

Comment: Funcionou do jeito que estava, só faltava uma concatenação simples, hehe.